# How to give access to Azure Functions in the Azure Portal

Tags: azure, function, roles, azure-powershell

I have a developer that needs to gain access to the Azure Functions section in the Azure Portal. I do not want to give him Global Admin rights to get there and looking at trying to create a Role for this. I have found this resource (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations) and I think I would need to give him access to the microsoft.web area.

Going into the Custom role creation, I do not have the option to pick any of the microsoft.web options.

Any assistance with the creation of the Role for all the Microsoft.Web options using the console or PowerShell would be greatly appreciated

Comment: just give them Contributor permissions on the Function App resource https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce the same and got the below output,

AFAIK, to Custom role creation you need Global Admin rights.

1. Open Power Shell and follow below steps
2. Login to Azure portal using below command

   `Connect-AzAccount`

[image]

3. Once login done follow the below command, it will give all the `Microsoft.Web` list

   `Get-AzProviderOperation "Microsoft.Web/*" | FT Operation, Description -AutoSize`

[image]

4. You have to give the path where the file must be saved like here  `"C:\CustomRoles"`.

```
Get-AzRoleDefinition -Name "Reader" | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File C:\CustomRoles\ReaderSupportRole.json
```

5. Open the  `ReaderSupportRole.json`  file in VS Code and use the below code,

```json
{    
"Name": "Support Tickets",    
"IsCustom": true,    
"Description": "View everything in the subscription and also open support tickets.",    
"Actions": [    
"Microsoft.Web/*/read"    
],   
"NotActions": [],    
"DataActions": [],    
"NotDataActions": [],    
"AssignableScopes": [
"/subscriptions/0000000-00000000-000000-000000"
]
}
```

6. Enter the Subscriptions in the place “000000-00000-00000-00000” and save the file.

To get the subscription Id, use the below command.

```
Get-AzSubscription
```

7. The below command is used to deploy the file into Azure Portal.

```
New-AzRoleDefinition -InputFile "C:\CustomRoles\ReaderSupportRole.json"
```

After executing the above command, you will get below output,

[image]

8. To confirm whether the given file deployed successfully or not, use below command to check the status.

```
Get-AzRoleDefinition | ? {$_.IsCustom -eq $true} | FT Name, IsCustom
```

You will get the below output,

[image]